Adding a variable to some PHP code with gettext
The year in the following code, that is to say “2024”
$titolo_display_price = '<div class="titolo_listino_prezzi" ID="titolo_listino_prezzi">' . '<h3 class="titolo_affitti">' . esc_html__('Rates 2024 in &euro;/ week:','mysite-plugin') . '</h3>' .'</div>';

should be tranformed in a variable such as
$current_year = get_the_author_meta( 'current_year', $user->ID )

How can I transform the first code adding the variable?

Use sprintf():
// Translators: %s: author's current year.
esc_html( sprintf( __('Rates %s in &euro;/ week:','mysite-plugin'), $current_year ) );

This is a common pattern that can be found in WordPress core. The Translators: comment is also essential to provide translators with context to translate the passage and understand what the placeholder %s will contain.

I cant see the variable output. Pls note that the get_the_author_meta() is in a file included in functions, instead the $titolo_display_price is in a custom plugin.

ok, it's allright, I forgot to declare the variable!
